# How to match a complete inputted string that contains a 'word' and a 'number xx' using RegEx?

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I mean, I need to check if the string contains a word and a number in the following order:
`wordXX`. For example, `fruit23` and regex returns true. Else if string like `fru103` Regex will return false. Hope, anyone's help me.

Comment: a regular expression can't know what is a word and what is just a collection of chars. To a regex, `apple34` and `hstje76` are the same unless you specify specific chars.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you case use :

```
[A-z]+\d\d
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this regex:

`^[a-zA-Z]+\\d{2}$`

---

Or simply:

`^word\\d{2}$`

---

Upd:

To match from `instance1` to `instance99` you have to use:

`^instance[1-9]{1}\\d?$`

Example:
https://ideone.com/tuijJY

Comment: Yeap, it is nearly my case. But can I somehow replace this amount of symbols `[a-zA-Z]` to a whole word and then compare it with my string?

Comment: @LabLab what is your string? `fruit`?

Comment: no, but does it matter?

Comment: my string is 'instance' + number [1..99]

Comment: @LabLab please see edited answer. Or `^instance\\d{2}$`

Comment: Well I see, the last question is: how do I exclude the zero from this number? so a whole string should be like 'instance1' to a 'instance99'. If there is 'instance0' regex returns false

Comment: @LabLab see update in the answer plus example.